# Задача на Резервное копирование

Tags: c#

Все задание на скринах, весь день сидим и не можем понять как это сделать. Результат выводится, но остается ненужная 5 в 3-й строке. Помогите пожалуйста

[image: 1 часть]

[image: 2 часть]

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ZADACHA3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\inputdata.txt";
            int i = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                int nom = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                string[] input = new string[nom];
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    input[i] = line;
                    i++;
                }
                int[] num = new int[8];

                for (int k = 0; k < nom; k++)
                {
                    num = input[k].Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

                    for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
                    {
                            if (num[j] > num[j - 1])
                            { 
                                Console.Write($"{j-1} ");
                                continue;

                            }

                            if (num[j] != num[7])
                            {
                                if (j == 6)
                                {
                                Console.Write(num[7]);
                                break;

                                }
                            }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вникал в подробности вашего алгоритма, но, по моему, тут отлично подходит обычный стек. Например

```
var input = @"D:\temp\SO\1048088\input.txt";
var output = @"D:\temp\SO\1048088\output.txt";
using(var sr = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(input))))
{
    var n = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    var stack = new Stack<int>();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var data = sr.ReadLine().Split(" ").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        var day = data[7];
        stack.Push(day);
        for (int j = day; j >= 0; j--)
            if (data[j] < data[stack.Peek()]) stack.Push(j);            

        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(' ', stack));
        stack.Clear();
    }

    File.WriteAllText(output, sb.ToString());       
}
```

На входе

```
4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
0 8 8 8 8 8 8 3
0 2 3 4 5 6 7 4
0 7 2 6 3 5 4 4
```

На выходе

```
4
0 3
0 1 2 3 4
0 2 4
```